# Express and NGINX with Sub Domains on same Server

Tags: angular, express, nginx

I have a issue and I've tried searching for a answer on here but have been unsuccessful. Originally I was using AWS Load balancer to handle my issue with express and sub domains running on specific ports. However this ended up breaking down recently and all I get is Gateway error.

So I decided to switch to just using Nginx with Express as I have a MEAN Stack application setup. However if I start the MEAN stack Application server.js file it loads different directories on different PORTS.

So for example the main .com website is at port 9000, the build app is at port 8500, the sign up app is at port 10000, and the live app is at port 8000. However If i configure nginx to have a subdomain file and the epxress server.js is running it just says the PORT is in use.

So my question is how do I correctly set this up? So that NGINX sets app. to the right location contained within Express. Or should I not even define ports and locations in side of Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do the following:

1) Delete what's in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*`, and this one as well `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

2) Create a **separate** config file for each site in `sites-available/` directory, e.g /`etc/nginx/sites-available/subdomain1.domain.com`. the content of each file should 
look like this.:

```
upstream upstream_name_x {
  server host_where_app_runs:9000;
}

server {
listen       80;
server_name  subdomain_x.domain.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://upstream_name_x/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
   }
}
```

3) Test the configuration file `nginx -t`. nginx reload is sufficient for these changes to take effect.

Comment: Ok thanks. Ill try that. I had not tried with the upstream config option yet.

Comment: The test was successful and express is running and I restarted NGINX however I'm just getting "Site can't be reached"... 

Do i need to keep the "_x" after the subdomain name in your config code and do need to change the proxy pass upstream name each time in each file?

Comment: Well, server_name should be the exact hostname you are using to reach your app from the web browser. Also the upstream name has to be unique among all your sites, and it has to match the value of proxy_pass for in the same config file.

Comment: well I modified everything and then ran ln -s to transfer it to sites-enabled and just get a 502 bad gateway currently.

Comment: alright, did you restart/reload nginx? if yes, can you check nginx logs both access and error? and what do you see if you do curl http://localhost:<port>/ to one of your apps?

Comment: hmm.. If i do localhost:port i see the correct pages that are suppose to load for each port i try. the nginx -t is successful. the only i error i see when i do service status is one that says Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: invalid argument

Comment: ok so now i got it working however the suddomain is showing the wrong info even though I have it configured right now at localhost:8500 in the config. The subdomains are showing the same info as the main site i mean.which is localhost port 9000... But if i test it in terminal the ports show the right info.

Comment: GOT IT! had to run the ln -s command to copy it to enabled. Thank you!